# Encryption of s3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

I am storing data in file in aws s3 and already enabled SSE. but i am curious to know is there a way to encrypt the  data so when someone download the file so they cant see the content??  I am just new to AWS and it would be great if somw one give the input

Comment: [Encrypt the data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) before you send it to S3, and don't share the decryption key with anyone that shouldn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) to encrypt the data prior to uploading it to an Amazon S3 bucket. Then the data will remain encrypted until it's decrypted using the key.  YOu can find an example here (for Java SDK)

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/KMSEncryptionExample.java

Answer (score 0):

> already enabled SSE.

SSE encrypts the content on S3, but an authenticated client cloud access the content in plain, the encryption is done under the hood and the client is unable to access the ciphertext (encrypted form)

You can use the default s3 key or a custom KMS key (CMS) , where the client need explicit access to decrypt the content.

> download the file so they cant see the content??

Then the content needs to be encrypted before the upload. AWS provides some support for the [client-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) but the client is free to implement its own encryption strategy and the key management.

To solve trouble with managing the keys on the client side, it's often more practical to stick with SSE and allow access to S3 or the used CMS (key) only to identities that must access the content.